# Stubborn single image insists on getting its own page

Tags: floats

Any ideas why this image (lower entry) gets its own picture while the other one (upper entry, not visible) does not?

[image]

---

Tried using scale=0.5 instead and it got inline instead. Probably some funky LaTeX thing going on with that it's on the end of the previous page otherwise.

Comment: `120mm` may be too large. May be you add `height` too while maintaining `keepaspectratio`.

Comment: @HarishKumar tried using scale=0.5 and it got inline.... quite confused.

Comment: For `width=120mm`, your picture has  height too large that won't fit in the current page. May be your picture has empty white area in the surrounding. That is the cause.

Comment: There are many things that influence the placement of figures; see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31) (possible duplicate).